# Getting "cURL error 7" connecting to hosted ElasticSearch servers using ElasticSearch PHP Client

Tags: php, elasticsearch, libcurl, rackspace-cloud

Trying to connect to ES hosted with ObjectRocket, but get the following error...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\TransportException' with message 'cURL error 7: See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html'
in /var/www/html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:201 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(25): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php(114): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php(159): React\Promise\Promise->React\Promise\{closure}(Object(React\Promise\FulfilledPromise))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php(128): React\Promise\Promise->settle(Object(React\Promise\FulfilledPromise))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php(177): React\Promise\Promise->resolve(Array)
#5 [internal function]: React\Promise\Promise->React\Promise\{closure}(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/react/pro in /var/www/html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php on line 201
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  use Elasticsearch;
  use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

  $multiHandler = ClientBuilder::multiHandler();

  $hosts = [
    'http://user:pass@0.es.objectrocket.com:10183',
    'http://user:pass@1.es.objectrocket.com:10183',
    'http://user:pass@2.es.objectrocket.com:10183',
    'http://user:pass@3.es.objectrocket.com:10183'
  ];

  $client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->setHandler($multiHandler)->build();

  $params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id',
    'body' => [
      'testField' => 'abc'
    ]
  ];

  $response = $client->index($params);
  print_r($response);
?>
```

But if I run the `curl` command from the terminal it I have no problem connecting...

```
curl -XGET http://user:pass@0.es.objectrocket.com:10183
```

Comment: `cURL error 7` means `Failed to connect() to host or proxy.` Are you running the `curl` command on the same host as the PHP code is hosted?

Comment: @Val Exactly, and yes--that's why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Have you tried without calling `setHandler` and using the default handler?

Comment: @Val Yes, I get the same exact results.

Comment: just to confirm you did try curl on terminal across all the es instances i.e `0.es, 1.es,2.es,3.es`  and all work ?

Comment: @keety yes, works on all instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think the package `php5-curl` extension is missing.
If you are using Ubuntu or Linux bases systems,

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

If you are using nginx, running the above command, would automatically restart php5-fpm, however if you are using apache2, do restart apache2 and php5-fpm

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```